# How to manage while-loop to reverse this print

Tags: python, while-loop

I have recently started coding and currently I'm doing an exercise where I need to create a program that prints "15, 14, 12, 9, 5". The program should be created with the pieces provided in the code. **This means that I can only move these lines of code around but not alter them or add new code**. I have reached a point where I can print "5, 9, 12, 14, 15", but I don't know how to reverse this with these "puzzle pieces". Could someone help me out?

EDIT: Got an answer, thanks!

```
i = 0
MAX = 5
sum = 0
j = MAX
while j > i:
    while i < MAX:
        sum += j
        print(sum)
        j -= 1
        i += 1
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried and post text version of image in question itself.

Comment: You could try `itertools.permutations` and `exec` :-P

Comment: @superbrain unfortunately I must use these exact lines of code in the exercise and can't add anything new.

Comment: @coderfrombiz You misunderstood. I'm suggesting to test all permutations of the lines to find the one that works.

Comment: @superbrain Ahh, right! Actually I have never done that. Thanks for the tip, I will familiarize myself with it.

Comment: I've never done that, either, and it was mostly a joke. I think it could be done, but if indentations are allowed to change after all, that makes it harder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work

```
i = 0
MAX = 5
while i < MAX:    
  sum = 0
  j = MAX
  while j > i:
    sum += j
    j -= 1
  i += 1
  print(sum)
```

Very interesting task they gave you :)

Comment: They're not allowed to alter the lines. You altered indentations.

Comment: @superbrain we were allowed to alter indentations. I should have mentioned that too!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
sum = 15
i = 1
while sum > 0:
    print(sum)
    sum -= i
    i += 1
```

Edit:

```
i = 0
MAX = 5
while i < MAX:
    sum = 0
    j = MAX
    while j > i:
        sum += j
        j -= 1
    i += 1
    print(sum)
```

Comment: He can only move the rows of code and not alter them

Comment: Oh, I just saw you said you can only move these rows of code around but not alter them or add new code.

Comment: Yes I was unclear first and edited it. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

if not using while:

Using `split()` on string converts it into a list, then used `[::-1]` to reverse a list, then used `replace()` to remove duplicate separator ",,"

```
",".join("15, 14, 12, 9, 5".split()[::-1]).replace(",,",",")
```